# Angular 2 / Ionic Content is behind Headerbar

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have the problem that I tried to extract the headerbar into a own component but if I use this new component the content of the page goes behind the headerbar.

Without extracting the header and using the same code directly in the HTML it works correctly.

My new Component:

**header-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-header-bar',
  templateUrl: 'header-bar.html'
})

export class MyHeaderBar {

   @Input() pageTitle : String;
   constructor() {}
 }
```

**header-bar.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{pageTitle}}</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The page I try to use it:

**home.html**

```
<my-header-bar  pageTitle="Einstellungen"> </my-header-bar>

<ion-content>
   <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
   This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
   that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  ...
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Why does it not work with my own component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do the same in an older version of Ionic, and I was facing the same issues. I asked that on the Ionic Slack channel and @mhartington (from Ionic team) said:

> **There is no way to create a global ion-navbar, as this is done on
>   purpose**. The point of having a navbar defined for each component is so
>   that we can properly animate the titles, navbar background color (if
>   you change them) and animate other properties needed.

And about creating a custom directive to avoid duplicating ion-header / ion-navbar html code:

> That will still creat errors with how angular2 content projection
>   works. **We have several issues that have been open when people try this
>   and the best answer is to not do it**.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using following code and have not faced any issue till now. I tried with following;

```
<ion-navbar navbar>
  <ion-title >{{title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

Following is ts file code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'navbar.html'
})


export class CommonNavbar {
    public title: string;

    constructor(
        private nav: NavController) {

    }

    setTitle(title: string){
        this.title = title;
        console.log(this.title);
    }
}
```

And using this in a following way:

```
<ion-header>
    <navbar></navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I had also added some styling to common navbar( like centering the title) and configured this from the component/page by using following code snippet.

```
import { CommonNavbar } from '../../components/shared_nav/navbar';

@ViewChild(forwardRef(() => CommonNavbar)) commonNavbar: CommonNavbar;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.commonNavbar.setTitle(title);
        this.commonNavbar.centerTitle(true);
 }
```