# ion-header overlaps the ion-content | Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a very simple app so far, but I can't figure out how to fix the overlapping of the content (header on top of the content). I have created a component `header` that contains the header as the name suggest.

**header.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="dark">
        <ion-title>
            Some Title
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I have been trying to use it on different pages, but it always overlaps the content of the page.

**page.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <h1>Some Page</h1>
</ion-content>
```

I have tried using `div` tag instead of `ion-content`, and also tried using `class="has-header"`, but nothing seems to be working. Although, if don't use the `header` as a component such as the following, it works fine. But I want to use the `header` as a component so that I can reuse it on other pages.

**page.html (don't want to have it like this)**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="dark">
        <ion-title>
            Some Title
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <h1>Some Page</h1>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 / Ionic Content is behind Headerbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948322/angular-2-ionic-content-is-behind-headerbar)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-content-is-cut-off-by-the-ion-header/57247/5) of Ionic official forum by @brandyshea of Ionic team, the thing is that in one page you can only have 3 kind of tags as top tags, everything else must go inside one of them. The 3 tags are:

```
<ion-header></ion-header>
<ion-content></ion-content>
<ion-footer></ion-footer>
```

I was trying to organize my app as @Hafiz and stumbled on the same problem, the solution has been to put my custom header (*`<ew-navigazione-top>`*) inside *`<ion-header>`* in each page.

```
<ion-header>
<ew-navigazione-top [ew_title]="navParams.get('label')" [ew_subtitle]="The subtitle"></ew-navigazione-top>
</ion-header>
```

P.S. This is the solution for Ionic 3. **For previous versions** on the same linked thread you can find other specific solutions.

Comment: this is not working for me on ionic 3, header still overlaps ion-content.  Edit: I was using ion-header tag also inside the component, now it's removed and works fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try with below :

```
<app-header></app-header>
<ion-content style="margin-top:__px">
<h1>Some Page</h1>
</ion-content>
```